# does anyone has used Ivona library?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, ivona

I am using IVONA library to text-to-speech, everything works fine but I am facing one issue

on keyboard space key press I need to speak the written word before space, this is also working fine when user type slowly, but when user type word fast at that time ivona crash and gives me this error

```
libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000080 (code=1), thread 15441 (Thread-2170)
libc: Send stop signal to pid:15384 in void debuggerd_signal_handler(int, siginfo_t*, void*)
```

here is my ivona code

```
 public void readWord_Sentence(final String word) {
     new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int sampleRate = initStreamer(word, false);

                if (sampleRate == -1) return;

                int numSamples = sampleRate / 10;

                if (mStreamer != null) {
                    JIvonaWave w;
                    while ((w = mStreamer.synth(numSamples)) != null) {
                        if (mTrack == null) {
                            mTrack = createAudioTrack(sampleRate);
                        }
                        short[] samples = w.getSamples();
                        mTrack.write(samples, 0, samples.length);
                        mTrack.play();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                stopWord_Sentence();
            }// end finally
        }
    }.start();

}


/**
 * Force stop word or sentences
 */
 public synchronized void stopWord_Sentence() {
    if (mStreamer != null) {
        try {
            synchronized (mStreamer) {
                mStreamer.stop();
                mStreamer = null;
            }
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InternalException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (mTrack != null) {
        try {
            mTrack.flush();
            mTrack.stop();
            mTrack.release();
            mTrack = null;
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to comment all code, and got the error is occurring on this line `mStreamer.synth(numSamples)`

I am using .so files for ivona and the error is in `libtts_engine.so` file

**EDIT**

this code is inside the keyboard `space` click method

```
 Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();

                if (!readingWordOrSentence.trim().equals("")) {
                    executor.execute(() -> keyboardTextReader.readWord_Sentence(readingWordOrSentence.trim()));
                }
            }
        };
        thread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        thread.start();
```

and above code is inside `readWord_Sentence()` to read word.

Comment: I think you should use register handler in _run()_ method of thread and move your code to _handleMessage()_ method of handler as per your requirement.

Comment: @Piyush it works, now app does not crash, but I need to do it in a background thread, how can I do this? My app goes stuck when I perform this in the main thread

Comment: Use _AsyncTask_ then.

Comment: in AsyncTask I also get the same error

Comment: Have you moved your code in _doInBackground()_ method?

Comment: yes, I moved my code in `doInBackground()`

Comment: So app is crashing or something else?

Comment: I have a keyboard, and this code is on keyboard's space keypress, and the only keyboard is crashing not the whole app, the keyboard is on different process

Comment: Is it your own customized keyboard or native?

Comment: my own customized keyboard

Comment: Then for space how you handled that? Can i see that snippet ?

Comment: Question edited. Please check

Comment: For keyboard space instead of thread have you used _AsyncTask_?

Comment: yes tried, but not working

Comment: So it means it's thread inside thread

Comment: yes, its thread inside thread and also executror inside thread

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197195/discussion-between-piyush-and-priyankagb).